# How to filter elements based on height to fit into a container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, waveform

Maybe this is more of a maths question, I just don't know how to start calculating.

[image: Waveform]

I have an array of elements(Wave peaks).

These elements come with different heights for different arrays, but the width for each element is 2px with a right margin of 1px.

These elements have to be appended into a container div to form an interactive audio wave. Width of the container is 700px, so only about 233.5 elements can fit into the container at max.

How do I filter the elements to fit into the container by not appending elements with smaller heights so that the elements in the container come close to being >= 232 < 234.

Here's a Fiddle of this example. https://jsfiddle.net/8ko3dozj/

```
$.create_waves = function(){    
            $.append = function(h){
            $.each(wave_columns, function(index, item){
                var peak_height = item*max_peak_remaining_space;
                if (item > h){
                var wave_peak_div = '<nav class="wave_column_div">\
                <div class="wave_column_div_inner" data-height="'+peak_height+'">\
                </div>\
                </nav>';
                $('#wave_result').append(wave_peak_div);
                }
            });
            }
            var length = wave_columns.length;
            //alert(length);
        $.append(0.3);  
        $.animate_peak_height();
        var num_peaks = $('.wave_column_div').length;
        if (num_peaks < 233){
            //$.append(0.5);
            }
        }       
        $.create_waves();
```

**Notes:** I don't want to use overflow:hidden for more than 3 elements(peaks) as that will take out the important parts of the audio used for seeking. Taking out low peaks zooms the waveform, as I see it, that's why I prefer it that way.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're asking how to make it so that wave isn't cut in the middle of a "downward" slope?

Comment: @ElliotM I want to remove low peaks from the wave so that important peaks (Visible Peaks) can fit in the wave container without overflowing, and with that, all visible peaks should not be greater than 233 in length, meaning if they are, they must be reduced by taking out the lowest peaks among them until we have 233 elements remaining in the container. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible algorithm:

1. Create a copy of your `wave_columns` array.
2. Sort it in an descending order to get the biggest ones first
3. Slice it to keep only 233 (or less) waves
4. The last value is your `min_height`

In code:

```
var copy = wave_columns.slice(0,wave_columns.length-1);
copy.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
copy = copy.slice(0,233);
var min_height = copy[copy.length-1];
```

### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: Hehe, good idea, So how do you map back a sorted copy into its initial order? I saw the fiddle, Just wanna make sure the peaks are not shuffled and also make sure I understand your code.

Comment: @Relm That's why I created a copy, so that the original array remains untouched. The only purpose of this piece of code is to find out the `min_height`. Nothing else. Then you can just do `$.append(min_height);`, which will use the original (unsorted) array.

Comment: Ok I hear you, i'm still testing with different arrays for different waveforms. Will come back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but you can use a counter (`maxpeaks`) to keep track how many peaks are in the container. When you have enough peaks you can terminate the each loop by returning false.

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/8ko3dozj/2/)

```
$.create_waves = function(){
    var maxpeaks = 233;
    $.append = function(h){
    $.each(wave_columns, function(index, item){
        if(maxpeaks == 0){
                return false;
        }
        var peak_height = item*max_peak_remaining_space;
        if (item > h){
        maxpeaks--;
        var wave_peak_div = '<nav class="wave_column_div">\
        <div class="wave_column_div_inner" data-height="'+peak_height+'">\
        </div>\
        </nav>';
        $('#wave_result').append(wave_peak_div);
        }
    });
    }
    var length = wave_columns.length;
    //alert(length);
$.append(0.3);  
$.animate_peak_height();
var num_peaks = $('.wave_column_div').length;
if (num_peaks < 233){
    //$.append(0.5);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you understand, but the important point is we don't just want to fill the container, I want to fill the container with elements(peaks) that more visible(Highest values of the array). In this case, by removing low peaks. In your logic, you stop the loop without evaluating which peaks are high and which are low. We are suppose to remove low peaks not any remaining peaks. So stopping the loops simply because the index > 233 is not right.

Comment: the counter only decrement when `item > h` so there are no peaks smaller then `h`

Comment: Still, lets say you have 2000 peaks, the first 400 are less than < then the next 233 are > h, this will append that 233 and not continue to get the rest of the peaks to compare them with the first 200. h cannot be a fixed value I think, that's where I'm missing it.